# login with curl and get session

Tags: php, api, curl

hello i need somehow to get top Regional interest and interest over time from

http://www.google.com/trends?q=lingerie+&ctab=0&geo=id&date=all&sort=0

or better

http://www.google.com/insights/search/#q=lingerie&geo=ID&cmpt=q

**so i found out that we have to login to export data** can anybody give me an example doing this with our google username and password? maybe using curl to export the data? or something else

Thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: Does Google even have an API for trends/search insights? As far as I've seen, the only google insights available in an API was youtube insights. If there is an API for this, could you please provide the link?

Comment: no.. but there is an downloadable CSV. and it olny can be downloadable when we logged in ( see google auth thing ). thats the problem i dont know how to use curl well to send something like "hello this is me im login let me download the .CSV file".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to be quick about it, I used my [xhttp class](http://codecri.me/sources/includes/class-xhttp-php/) which is a curl wrapper, and I think the code is easy enough to follow.

```
<?php

header('content-type: text/plain');

// Set account login info
$data['post'] = array(
  'accountType' => 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',  // indicates a Google account
  'Email'       => '',  // full email address
  'Passwd'      => '',
  'service'     => 'trendspro', // Name of the Google service
  'source'      => 'codecri.me-example-1.0' // Application's name, e.g. companyName-applicationName-versionID
);

$response = xhttp::fetch('https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin', $data);

// Test if unsuccessful
if(!$response['successful']) {
    echo 'response: '; print_r($response);
    die();
}

// Extract SID
preg_match('/SID=(.+)/', $response['body'], $matches);
$sid = $matches[1];

// Erase POST variables used on the previous xhttp call
$data = array();

// Set the SID in cookies
$data['cookies'] = array(
    'SID' => $sid
);

$response = xhttp::fetch('http://www.google.com/insights/search/overviewReport?q=lingerie&geo=ID&cmpt=q&content=1&export=1', $data);

// CSV data in the response body
echo $response['body'];

?>
```

The result is at: http://codecri.me/apps/test/test.google.trends.php
But I'm not sure if the result is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Adam Is there something missing with my answer? I was hoping to get my first bounty lol.

Comment: nope, your the best mate. btw why 25? i still dont know how this thing work. lol. anyway thanks!

Comment: @Adam I got half the bounty, 25, 'cause I got the most upvotes but the asker didn't mark it as accepted within the bounty period.

Answer (score 1):

Since April 2012 Google changed it's auth policy, edit the Arvin's code as follows:

```
// Extract Auth
preg_match('/Auth=(.+)/', $response['body'], $matches);
$auth = $matches[1];

// Erase POST variables used on the previous xhttp call
$data = array();

// Set the Authorization header
$data['headers'] = array(
    'Authorization' => 'GoogleLogin auth='.$auth
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The curl man page describes how to provide username and password.  Have you tried the -u flag?

-u/--user 
       Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication. Overrides -n/--netrc and --netrc-optional.

```
   If you just give the user name (without entering a colon) curl will prompt for a password.

   If you use an SSPI-enabled curl binary and do NTLM authentication, you can force curl to pick up the user name  and  password from your environment by simply specifying a single colon with this option: "-u :".

   If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
```