# How download with php google trends/insign cvs file?

Tags: php

How download with php google trends/insign cvs file?

reproduce:

1. go to :
   http://www.google.com/trends?q=london%2C+paris&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0
2. in this page exist option to download cvs file that have all query result data by click.
   I need to that by php.

Thanks,

Yosef

Comment: use file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/trends/viz?q=london,+paris&date=all&geo=all&graph=all_csv&sort=0&sa=N)

Answer (score 2):

```
$query   = 'london, paris';
$csvFile = 'http://www.google.com/trends/viz?q='.urlencode($query).'&date=all&geo=all&graph=all_csv&sort=0&sa=N';

file_put_contents(file_get_contents($link), 
                  str_replace(array(',', ' ') '-', $query).'.cvs');
```

Answer (score 2):

[look](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) on the `file_get_contents` function

```
<?php
$csv = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/trends/viz?q=london,+paris&date=all&geo=all&graph=all_csv&sort=0&sa=N');    
echo $csv;
?>
```

Comment: Not working: I get: "You must be signed in to export data from Google Trends"

Comment: ok, i see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101151/get-google-trends-insights-with-php-login-auth-google