# How download cvs file with google authorization in google insights - have to use zend classes and not other php ways (zend_gbase etc.. )

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-gdata

How download cvs file with google authorization in google trends service - have to use zend framework classes and not other php [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342584/how-download-with-php-google-trends-insign-cvs-file) .

Thanks,

Yosef

Comment: It's not Zend, but probably this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101151/get-google-trends-insights-with-php-login-auth-google

Comment: i need only zend, this link exist in 'ways'

Comment: zend has a HTTP client as well. So you could stick to that one.

Comment: What do you mean by "have to use Zend Framework classes"? Zend IS php and you can extend Zend in any way possible and implement those "other php ways" easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be what you need. You need to enter your Google username and password in the `$email` and `$passwd` variables and to setup the autoloader or require ZF classes.

References: [Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.clientlogin.html) and [ClientLogin](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html)

```
// setup the autoloader first or require used classes
// using the example code in the example to get auth tokens
try {
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $passwd, 'xapi', $httpClient);
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_CaptchaRequiredException $cre) {
    echo 'URL of CAPTCHA image: ' . $cre->getCaptchaUrl() . "\n";
    echo 'Token ID: ' . $cre->getCaptchaToken() . "\n";
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $ae) {
    echo 'Problem authenticating: ' . $ae->exception() . "\n";
}

// extract authentication tokens from response body
$ck_count = preg_match_all('/^(.+)=(.+)$/m', $client->getLastResponse()->getBody(), $cookies);

// build a new http client
$auth = new Zend_Http_Client('http://www.google.com/trends/viz?q=facebook&graph=all_csv&sa=N');

for ($i = 0; $i < $ck_count; $i++) {
    // authenticate it using the provided tokens as cookies
    $auth->setCookie($cookies[1][$i], $cookies[2][$i]);
}
// make the request and dump cvs data
Zend_Debug::dump($auth->request()->getBody());
```

Output given (truncated for brevity):

```
facebook, facebook (std error)
1.00, 0%


Week, facebook, facebook (std error)
Jan 4 2004, 0, >10%
Jan 11 2004, 0, >10%
Jan 18 2004, 0, >10%
Jan 25 2004, 0, >10%
Feb 1 2004, 0, >10%
Feb 8 2004, 0, >10%
Feb 15 2004, 0, >10%
Feb 22 2004, 0, >10%
Feb 29 2004, 0, >10%
```

Comment: thank you very much - looks great, I going to check how its works

Comment: How can you add headers to be  a browser?

Comment: `$auth->setHeaders('YourHeader', 'foobar');` see [http client doc](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/_Http_Client.html#Zend_Http_Client::setHeaders())